# SQL Query to convert single row from multiple tables into a single row in table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 7 tables with same structure. And each table has 2 columns,In these one column is join key( but not a primary key) and 2nd column is Unique.

Below is the requirement mentioned for 2 tables. But we need to develop for 7 tables.

```
TAB1:
=====
CITY    NAME
HYD     RAMU
HYD     KRISH


TAB1:
=====
CITY    NAME
HYD     RAJ
HYD     KRISH

OUTPUT:
=======

CITY   EXIST1   EXIST2
HYD     RAMU     NULL 
HYD     NULL     RAJ
HYD     KRISH    KRISH
```

Answer (score 1):

An answer with 4 tables - it should be fairly easy to expand it to 7 tables.

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 ( city, name ) AS
SELECT 'a', 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 'b' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE t2 ( city, name ) AS
SELECT 'a', 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 'c' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE t3 ( city, name ) AS
SELECT 'a', 'b' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 'd' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE t4 ( city, name ) AS
SELECT 'a', 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 'e' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT COALESCE( t1.city, t2.city, t3.city, t4.city ) AS city,
       t1.name AS exist1,
       t2.name AS exist2,
       t3.name AS exist3,
       t4.name AS exist4
FROM   t1
       FULL OUTER JOIN t2
       ON (    t1.city = t2.city
           AND t1.name = t2.name )
       FULL OUTER JOIN t3
       ON (    COALESCE( t1.city, t2.city ) = t3.city
           AND COALESCE( t1.name, t2.name ) = t3.name )
       FULL OUTER JOIN t4
       ON (    COALESCE( t1.city, t2.city, t3.city ) = t4.city
           AND COALESCE( t1.name, t2.name, t3.name ) = t4.name );
```

**Output**:

```
CITY EXIST1 EXIST2 EXIST3 EXIST4
---- ------ ------ ------ ------
a    a      a             a
a    b             b
a           c
a                  d
a                         e
```

Comment: Thanks MTO, I hope above query  defiantly will work for my scenario. I will test it with my scenario and will get back you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are after a `FULL JOIN`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.CITY, t2.CITY), t1.NAME AS EXIST1, t2.NAME AS EXIST2
FROM TAB1 AS t1
FULL JOIN TAB2 ON AS t2 ON t1.CITY = t2.CITY
```

Comment: This does not join on the `name` column and does not consider the OP's requirement for more than 2 tables.

Comment: Hi Giorgos, Thanks for your reply. If I execute above query, we didn't get expected result since join key values always match,so no problem with join key. Tricky point with 2nd column. In the above example, 'RAMU' exists in 1st table but not in 2nd table.So output table should show null value. In 2nd table,'RAJ' is exist in 2nd table but not exist in 1st table,so for this value output should shows null value. Please let me know if you need more details on this.